# Can the MQTT output be inferred from test server instructions?

Tags: mqtt

A test MQTT broker can be found at: http://test.mosquitto.org/.  The website suggests trying the command:

```
 mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "#" -v
```

I believe that the "#" denote a wildcard for topics, which would show any topic and its payload.

A raspberry pi has successfully run the mosquitto command per [instructables MQTT example](https://www.instructables.com/id/Installing-MQTT-BrokerMosquitto-on-Raspberry-Pi/), however **no output is observed with the above command.**

It is unclear if there is an entity publishing to the test server that would return a result in the subscribing client.  This could be on reason that I am not observing anything.  I would think there are other possible obstacles / pitfalls and look forward to enlightening responses.

Attempts to publish to a topic failed as described in: [MQTT Error: Connection Lost](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/534236/)

Comment: Did you publish anything to any topic? Of course there's no output while no client publishes anything.

Comment: @Murphy [Yes, An attempt to publish is documented in this hyperlinked stackexchange posting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/534236/182280)

Answer (score 1):

To answer your original question: Yes, something needs to be published in order to show a reaction for the subscribed topic. And yes, `#` is a wildcard, like `*` is for shell. And `mosquitto_sub` would just listen until you terminate it.

Regarding the connection issue, from the [webpage](https://test.mosquitto.org/):

> This means that it will often be running unreleased or experimental code and may not be as stable as you might hope.

I experience the same problem, but was able to use `iot.eclipse.org` successfully. There's much traffic there, so better use a specific topic instead of `#`, but it proves that the subscription is working as expected. For your tests, just pick one from the [public brokers list](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers) that doesn't require signup.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful response: I have been able to reproduce your results at `iot.eclipse.org`    Replacing the MQTT broker with iot.eclipse.org. demonstrates that the listener command syntax is correct: iot.eclipse.org has significant traffic in August 2019.  Until a payload is received on the test.mosquitto.org, I do not think we can conclude anything: it could be a stability problem as indicated by Murphy or it could be nobody is publishing payloads to the test.mosquitto .org