# MQTT Error: Connection Lost

Tags: mqtt

A 'listener' console was setup:

```
mosquitto_sub -h test.mosquitto.org -t "myTopic" -v
```

`mosquitto_pub` returns an error:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org  -t 'myTopic' -m 'hello world'
**Error: The connection was lost.**
```

What steps, from the command line, can be taken to diagnose if there is a syntax problem?

Update:

Replacing the MQTT server with `iot.eclipse.org` does not suffer the error and returns payloads as expected.

Listener console setup:

```
mosquitto_sub -h iot.eclipse.org -t "myTopic" -v
```

Send payload:

```
mosquitto_pub -h iot.eclipse.org -t 'myTopic' -m 'hello world'
```

`mosquitto_pub` returns:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_sub -h iot.eclipse.org -t "myTopic" -v
myTopic hello world
```

Publish a payload:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org  -t 'myTopic' -m 'hello world'
```

Changing the MQTT broker demonstrates there is not a syntax error, however, the question remains why there is an error returned in the original testing

Comment: @jsotola This comment is not helpful. For starters, what documentation are you referring to?

Comment: the mosquitto.org documentation

Comment: @jsotola  Comments issued in the imperative (as opposed to the interrogative or declarative) may be construed as disrespectful, especially if they are deemed not helpful.

Comment: @gatorback, you wanted to know how to determine if there is a syntax error ... the place to start is to find out what the server expects to receive from your device

Comment: @jsotola  If you have solution, I suggest posting a response with code examples as an answer below.   I am  looking forward to constructive solution to the question: enter the bonus round if you can nail down root cause of the error returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [webpage](https://test.mosquitto.org/):

> This means that it will often be running unreleased or experimental code and may not be as stable as you might hope.

I experience the same problem, but was able to use `iot.eclipse.org` successfully. There's much traffic there, so better use a specific topic instead of `#`. For your tests, just pick one from the [public brokers list](https://github.com/mqtt/mqtt.github.io/wiki/public_brokers) that doesn't require signup.

Answer (score 0):

I found that adding the --insecure option solved this error for me.

```
mosquitto_pub -t mqtt-topic -m "sample-msg-1" --insecure
```

My mqtt server is all internal with the port all within docker so, the --insecure option doesn't really add any additional exposure for my case.  I'm not sure why that worked for me since I think it should be using mqqt (unencrypted) as opposed to mqqts (encrypted)

Comment: Can you explain what the `--insecure` option ***does**?* … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.